# Static Block Unprocessed in java

Tags: java

While accessing final static variable with class name why static block is not being processed in java?

```
class Foo {
  public static final int BAR;
  static {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    }
  }
class Baz {
  public static void quux() {
    System.out.println(Foo.BAR);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

It will sometimes - it depends on whether the variable is actually a *constant*:

- It has to be either a string or a primitive variable (*possibly* any other class with a null value; I'd have to check)
- The initialization expression has to be a constant expression

If that's the case, any references to the variable are effectively turned into the value. So in this code:

```
class Foo {
    public static final int BAR = 5;
}

class Baz {
    public static void quux() {
        System.out.println(Foo.BAR);
    }
}
```

The method in `Baz` is compiled into the same code as:

```
public static void quux() {
    System.out.println(5);
}
```

There's no hint of `Foo.BAR` left in the bytecode, therefore `Foo` doesn't need to be initialized when the method executes.

If you want to prevent that from happening, you always just make it not be initialized with a constant expression in a variable initializer. For example:

```
class Foo {
    public static final int BAR;

    static {
        BAR = 5;
    }
}

class Baz {
    public static void quux() {
        System.out.println(Foo.BAR);
    }
}
```

That would be enough to make `Foo.BAR` not count as a constant as far as the compiler is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

The static block will only be executed when your class loads. This will be done in the following cases:

1. Initially when your program starts
2. If you load your class manually at runtime

   Ex : using Class.forName("Foo"))